# Python-postgresql backend, asp.net middle & frontend for desktop application development: does this work or are there better alternatives?

Tags: python, asp.net, pandas, data-analysis, desktop-application

I have an application dealing with data manipulation that I need to use the pandas library to develop. My question is if I'm using python to develop the main algorithms, can I use ASP.NET for the application or are there better alternatives?

Its a desktop app, not a web-app. I'm new to this so any advice would help- thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.